# Spring Security Websockets authenticate via console

Tags: java, spring

I have this Spring websocket security configuration. I want to authenticate the user via console(terminal) not in browser but have no idea how to do this.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("tet").password("123").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("123").roles("ADMIN");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("dba").password("123").roles("DBA");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {

        messages.simpDestMatchers("/chat/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").anyMessage().authenticated();
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the browser and the console differ? I don't really understand the requriement.

Comment: As far as i know Spring Security provides custom login form for user authentication. I do no know how to authenticate the use via console ?

Comment: What is "the console"? The standard way of doing non-interactive authentication is with an API token.

Comment: May be i do not have enough experience with spring security but that`s why i post the question.

Comment: Further, it should be obvious that anything a browser can do, any other method of access can do.